# Spring Boot web service client authentication

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, spring-ws

My goal is to call web service, which is require authentification (when I opne it's wsdl in my browser, browser asks me login+password).

As a base, I use the sample from [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) tutorial.

And now I have to add authentification configurations.

Accoding to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) something like configuring WebServiceTemplate bean may help.

But with Spring Boot there are no applicationContext.xml or any other configuration xml's in a project.

So, how to configure WebServiceTemplate using Spring Boot, or what else can solve such task?

Comment: You can always import xml with `@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spring Boot you are able to configure your beans with the `@Bean` annotation. You can use configuration classes for different beans. In those classes you need the `@Configuaration` annotation.

This [tutorial](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/spring-4-soap-request-with-http-basic-authentication/) describes the "second part" of the Spring tutorial. The main things of provided tutorial is: (based on the Spring tutorial)

> **The problem**
>
> The SOAP webservice I consume requires basic http authentication, so I
>   need to add authentication header to the request.
>
> **Without authentication**
>
> First of all you need to have implemented a request without the
>   authentication like in the tutorial on the spring.io. Then I will
>   modify the http  request with the authentication header.
>
> **Get the http request in custom WebServiceMessageSender**
>
> The raw http connection is accessible in the WeatherConfiguration
>   class. There in the weatherClient you can set the message sender in
>   the WebServiceTemplate. The message sender has access to the raw http
>   connection. So now it’s time to extend the
>   HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender and write custom implementation of it
>   that will add the authentication header to the request. My custom
>   sender is as follows:

```
public class WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth extends HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender{

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection)
        throws IOException {

    BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    String userpassword = "yourLogin:yourPassword";
    String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode( userpassword.getBytes() );
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);

    super.prepareConnection(connection);
}

@Bean
public WeatherClient weatherClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller){

WebServiceTemplate template = client.getWebServiceTemplate();
template.setMessageSender(new WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth());

return client;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved by following.
Basic idea was to create `CredentialsProvider` with basic username and password along with `AuthScope.ANY`:

```java
@Bean
public WebServiceMessageSender showReqMessageSender(@Value("${ws.username}") String username,
        @Value("${ws.passowrd}") String password) throws Exception {

    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    return new HttpComponentsMessageSender(
        HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor()).build());
}
```

Just for further info, this message sender bean is further used (set using class extedning WebServiceGatewaySupport)

```java
void org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport.setMessageSender(WebServiceMessageSender messageSender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another walk-around is to add an interceptor and add the requestHeader within the `handleRequest()` method from which the `HttpUrlConnection` can be easily derived from the `TransportContextHolder`;

here is the code of the interceptor class:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {

        TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();

        try {
            connection.addRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic VVNFUk5BTUU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    //TODO:: other methods and constructor..
}
```

and of course add the interceptor to the WebTemplate:

```
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[]{new SecurityInterceptor()};
webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uriWebService, request)
```