# SpringBoot WebService Client Unable to load data security for user ANONYMOUS Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webservicetemplate

I have written a Spring Boot Application which is having both Spring Boot Web and Spring Boot Webservices.

My POM looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Project SOAP Client with Rest FrontEnd</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <generatePackage>com.sptel.flowone.sri</generatePackage>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>WebService.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>  -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

For SOAP Client I following following Tutorial and I was able to generate client side code  successfully:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-soap-web-service

For Rest Front End I have create a simple rest controller as following :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/SRI")
public class SRIController {
    
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SRIController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private SRIClient sriClient; 
    
    
    
    
    @PostMapping("/getSRIOrderDetails")
    public RunActionResponse getSRIOrderDetails(@RequestBody SRIRequest sriRequest) {
        RunAction runAction = new RunAction();
        runaction.setOrderNumber(sriRequest.getOrderNumber);    
        RunActionResponse response =  sriClient.runAction(runAction);
        return response;
        
    }
}
```

But i am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Unable to load data security for user ANONYMOUS
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sptel.flowone.SRIClient.runAction(SRIClient.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sptel.flowone.controllers.SRIController.getSRIOrderDetails(SRIController.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_271]
```

below is SRIClient:

```
public class SRIClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport   {

    public RunActionResponse runAction(RunAction runAction) {
        
        
        WebServiceTemplate ws =   getWebServiceTemplate();
        
        RunActionResponse response = (RunActionResponse) ws.marshalSendAndReceive(runAction);
        return response;
    }
}
```

And below is configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SRIClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("context"); // Replaced due to data security 
        return marshaller;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SRIClient countryClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SRIClient client = new SRIClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("SRIWebServiceURL"); // Replaced due to data security 
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
       
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can guide me in right direction.

Comment: i guess the sample bases on an unprotected web service, where in your case the WS requires some authentication ... (finding out "the credentials"...and configuring your web service template like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35406361/592355) could help)

Comment: Web Service that I am calling do not require any security , I am able to invoke those endpoints without any authentication. For testing purpose I built a CXF Client outside my project as well that works fine.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and your `SRIClient` including its configuration.

Comment: I have updated the StackTrace

Comment: Added the Client and Configuration Code as well.

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for the pointer , I compared my code with SOAP UI working sample and found the issue .Under Run action there is a field "Useridentifier" which i was not setting. 

Also I was able to find the issue when i turned on debugging at TRACE level.

Comment: (with little more details+fix) consider to post it as an answer! ;) welcome 4pointing ... "Even a blind hen(me!) sometimes finds a grain of corn."  ..but of course "tracing & comparing" is the access to all (specific) soap exceptions. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my code , RunAction had a field where user name was suppose to set. I was assuming the given error message is being generated by SOAP Webservice template, turning on the debugging to trace level allowed me to find out that request is being sent to server and a response is being received.

I enabled the tracing for WS in spring using below in application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.ws=TRACE
```

This enabled me to find that request was being processed and also allowed me get the request XML where i was able to identify the missing param in the request sent to remote service.